# Ignore particular tag in cucumber but run all other tags

Tags: java, selenium, groovy, cucumber

I have a scenario, where I need to run multiple tags and need not run another one when a condition occurs. I don't want to run Feature_1 when the browser is IE.

```
@run_me @do_not_run
Feature 1
    
@Tag1 @Tag2
Scenario: Scenario 1
```

---

```
@run_me
Feature  2
    
@Tag1 @Tag3
Scenario: Scenario 2
```

Condition:

```
if(browser == "IE"){
    then execute all @run_me tags but don't execute it when there is @do_not_run
else
    run all @run_me
```

Current code:

```
--tags @run_me
```

What should be the right way to achieve it?

Note:
I tried `--tags @run_me ~@do_not_run`inside the if condition. But not sure it is the correct method or not.

Comment: I hope this can answer your query `@wip and not @slow -- > Scenarios tagged with @wip that aren’t also tagged with @slow` [Link](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tags)

Comment: Thank you Dilip for the comment. You may post this as "answer" with more details. You will get more points :)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below approach to execute the tags.

1. @fast -- Scenarios tagged with @fast
2. @wip and not @slow -- Scenarios tagged with @wip that aren’t also tagged with @slow
3. @smoke and @fast -- Scenarios tagged with both @smoke and @fast
4. @gui or @database --Scenarios tagged with either @gui or @database

[Reference Link](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tags)